# CSS is not working same as in CSS file as in HTML

Tags: html, css

When I put this code in my html file, it is working without issue:

```
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #headerimg 
    {
      display: block;
      background-image: url('/Content/images/epp/ebweblogo1.gif');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
            width:100%;
      height:100%;   
        margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
```

but when I move it to my css file as this:

```
#headerimg 
    {
      display: block;
      background-image: url('/Content/images/epp/ebweblogo1.gif');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
            width:100%;
      height:100%;   
        margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
    }
```

This is my html:

```
</head>
  <body>

    <div class="page">

      <div id="header">
      <div id="headerimg" />
```

I am assuming it's due to the image location but I'm not sure since I've tried variations of the path and never got it to work.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Sorry, you can't read my mind, I know.

When I place the css in the html file, the image displays fine. When I move it to the css file (site.css) it is not displaying at all. I've tried several different paths and it isn't being displayed no matter what I put in there.

**UPDATE #2**

When I change my html to this:

```
<div class="page">

  <div id="header">
    <div id="headerimg">test</div>
```

I am getting the image behind the text as 1 line that says test but not the full size of the image.

So it is apparently not displaying the image due to the size of the div? I changed the css to this:

height:130px;

but that did not change the height at all.

Comment: Are you aware that the leading slash before Content makes a reference to the site root?

Comment: I dont get your question properly. Is the entire css not applied when moved to a file or is it only the image?

Comment: Use Id selector & Class selector properly

Comment: Yes. Should I not be doing that?

Comment: @Cdeez only the image... I'll add clarification to my post

Comment: Silly question - how did you include the CSS file in the HTML?

Comment: How do you include CSS on the HTML? And please, could you tell us where is located your style.css and where your image exactly?

Comment: as the top code example shows

Comment: Ok, how does the image url look like in firebug or developer tools? Also what do the error consoles show?

Comment: I've updated my question, I think that will shed a little light on this.

Comment: I have figured out why the image wasn't showing. The height of the div is apparently zero. This causes the image to be hidden. I will submit a new question for why the height isn't working since that is not related to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two bits of CSS are not equivalent.

In one, you have `#headerimg` (id selector) which is a very different selector to `.headerimg` (class selector).

`#imgplacement` is also missing from the second sample.

---

As for the image issue - you need to ensure the correct path to the image directory.

This will be relative to where the CSS is - if in a `CSS` file, the image needs to be relative to the CSS file. If it is embedded in the HTML, it needs to be relative to the HTML file.

Since the path is rooted (starts with `/`), it should work everywhere. Use the developer tools to determine where it is looking for the image.

Comment: I fixed that, I was testing and forgot to change it back. Also, imageplacement isn't used, it was another test. Sorry, I cleaned it up.

Comment: @ErocM - So, what's the actual problem you are having? What's the directory structure like (location of HTML, CSS and image are all needed). Do you understand absolute and relative paths?

Comment: Yes I do. I can use the css in the html file and it shows without issue, when I move it to the css file, the image is not showing at all. I've tried various paths and I cannot get the image to show.

Comment: @ErocM - Did you do a hard refresh (Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: You should include it like this:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourstyle.css" media="all" />
And then be careful on where your image is located.

Answer (score 0):

Include your css like this on the home page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="route_to_your_style.css" media="all" />
```

And then be careful on routes for your image.

Answer (score 0):

include the CSS file between the `<head></head>` section of your `HTML` like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.yoursite.com/css/cssfile.css" />
```

Comment: I have this and the css is being used, thanks for the help though.